# android:singleLine="true" not working for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, focus

I used

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

in my AutoCompleteTextView layout.In keyboard after pressing **next** it is not focussing on next edit text.

Will `android:singleLine="true"` works on AutoCompleteTextView or I have to use some thing else to focus my cursor to next EditText?

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cityLyt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

            <TextView
                //Bla bla 
/>

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autoCity"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:hint="@string/enter_your_city"
                **android:singleLine="true"**           
                android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default" 
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/areaLyt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/cityLyt"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                //Bla bla
     />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edArea"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:hint="@string/enter_your_area"
                **android:singleLine="true"**
                android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to Set `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` in `AutoCompleteTextView` in xml .

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"  //in your xml file
```